# Persisting parent entity with OneToMany relationship make child entity entity_id field NULL in MySQL

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

So I have this Symfony 4 application where lies my main entity `Structure`. It has a property `$referent` (basically contact infos) stored with the below association:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Referent", mappedBy="structure", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $referent;
```

with its getters and setters:

```
/**
 * @return Collection|Referent[]
 */
public function getReferent(): Collection
{
    return $this->referent;
}

public function addReferent(Referent $referent): self
{
    if (!$this->referent->contains($referent)) {
        $this->referent[] = $referent;
        $referent->setStructure($this);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function removeReferent(Referent $referent): self
{
    if ($this->referent->contains($referent)) {
        $this->referent->removeElement($referent);
        // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
        if ($referent->getStructure() === $this) {
            $referent->setStructure(null);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Note that all the code has been automatically generated by `$ php bin/console make:entity`.

The problem is whenever I save a new `Structure` using `StructureType` form that embeds several `ReferentType` forms (as per [the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html)), both `Structure` and `Referent` entity are saved in the database except that `structure_id` in the `referent` table is set to `NULL` as per the below screenshot.

[image]

Here's the controller action that handles form display and submission:

```
/**
 * @Route("/add", name="back_add")
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function add(Request $request)
{
    $structure = new Structure();

    $form = $this->createForm(StructureType::class, $structure, [
        'attr' => ['id' => 'add-form'],
    ]);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted()) {

        $structure = $form->getData();

        $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $manager->persist($structure);
        $manager->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('back_update', ['id' => $structure->getId()]);
    }

    return $this->render('back/add.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'action' => __FUNCTION__,
    ]);
}
```

So why is that?

---

Also, please note that before adding `, cascade={"persist"}` on the relationship annotation, I had the following error on form submission:

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

---

#### Edit #1

As per requested, here the inverse side of the relationship:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Structure", inversedBy="referent")
 */
private $structure;
```

With its getters and setters:

```
public function getStructure(): ?Structure
{
    return $this->structure;
}

public function setStructure(?Structure $structure): self
{
    $this->structure = $structure;

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: There may be an issue with your `Referent::$structure` mapping. Please add the annotations for this property to your question!

Comment: @Benjamin > done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for Symfony form to correctly handling the collection with adder/remover, you need to add the option 'by_reference' => false in your StructureType class. Is that the case ?

```
$builder->add('referents', CollectionType::class, array('by_reference' => false))
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html

Comment: That wasn't! Adding `'by_reference' => false` in the array of options for the `referent` field in `StructureType` class did the trick! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the JoinColumn() annotation

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Structure", inversedBy="referent")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn()
 */
private $structure;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! Unfortunately, adding `@ORM\JoinColumn()` had no effect. `structure_id` column in `referent` table is still set to NULL.

Comment: @JoinColumn is optional if you use the default conventions.